# What's the cleanest (most Pythonic) way of creating a dictionary with list values from a sequence?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
stuff = [('key1', 1), ('key2', 2), ('key3', 3), 
         ('key1', 11), ('key2', 22), ('key3', 33),
         ('key1', 111), ('key2', 222), ('key3', 333),
         ]
# Note: values aren't actually that nice. That would make this easy.
```

I want to turn it into a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict_stuff = {'key1': [1, 11, 111],
              'key2': [2, 22, 222],
              'key3': [3, 33, 333],
              }
```

What's the nicest way to convert this data? The first method that comes to mind is:

```
dict_stuff = {}
for k,v in stuff:
    dict[k] = dict.get(k, [])
    dict[k].append(v)
```

Is that the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: if `stuff` was guaranteed to be sorted by the "key", I'd use `itertools.groupby`.  Since it appears that isn't the case, `collections.defaultdict` is probably your next best bet (as demonstrated in the answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), like this

```
dict_stuff = {}
for key, value in stuff:
    dict_stuff.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

It says that, if the `key` doesn't exist in the dictionary, then use the second parameter as the default value for it, otherwise return the actual value corresponding to the `key`.

We also have a built-in `dict` class, which helps you deal with cases like this, called [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_stuff = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in stuff:
    dict_stuff[key].append(value)
```

Here, if the `key` doesn't exist in the `defaultdict` object, the factory function passed to the `defaultdict` constructor will be called to create the value object.

Answer (score 1):

There is `defaultdict` in the `collections` lib.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dict_stuff = defaultdict(list) # this will make the value for new keys become default to an empty list
>>> stuff = [('key1', 1), ('key2', 2), ('key3', 3), 
...          ('key1', 11), ('key2', 22), ('key3', 33),
...          ('key1', 111), ('key2', 222), ('key3', 333),
...          ]
>>> 
>>> for k, v in stuff:
...     dict_stuff[k].append(v)
... 
>>> dict_stuff
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key3': [3, 33, 333], 'key2': [2, 22, 222], 'key1': [1, 11, 111]})
```

Comment: Note that if at some later point you want to turn off the "default" behavior of the default dict, you just set the `default_factory` attribute to `None`.  e.g. `dict_stuff.default_factory = None`

Answer (score 0):

```
stuff_dict = {}
for k, v in stuff:
    if stuff_dict.has_key(k):
        stuff_dict[k].append(v)
    else:
        stuff_dict[k] = [v]


print stuff_dict
{'key3': [3, 33, 333], 'key2': [2, 22, 222], 'key1': [1, 11, 111]}
```

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated, you can simply do `if k in stuff_dict:`